# Error one page checkout with city and region "Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field."

Tags: error, onepage-checkout

When I have a customer with a city like New York, it gives this error: Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.

Some with the region, you can not have a " " in it ? Where do I need to change this.

This is the site www.deli-discount.nl

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's some custom checkout extension that you are using so in order to see which is the template, you have to activate template path hints in the **admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Debug -> Template Path Hints: Yes** (you have to switch to **Website** in **Current Configuration Scope** in order too see this option).

Then in the template file you will see something like this:

```
<input name="billing[city]" id="billing:city" title="Plaats" value="" class="validate-alpha t1 required-entry" maxlength="20" type="text">
```

and this:

```
<input id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="" title="Provincie" class="validate-alpha t1" maxlength="20" style="" type="text">
```

Please change them to:

```
<input name="billing[city]" id="billing:city" title="Plaats" value="" class="validate-alphanum-with-spaces t1 required-entry" maxlength="20" type="text">
```

and:

```
<input id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="" title="Provincie" class="validate-alphanum-with-spaces t1" maxlength="20" style="" type="text">
```

In one word - change the class of the input fields from `validate-alpha` to `validate-alphanum-with-spaces`.

Comment: Super, that works perfect, is weird is standard in the checkout, but works fine now !! Thanks a lot